# FFMPEG -vf does not extract first frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running the following command to extract frames at a rate of 1 per second. This works fine, except that the first extracted frame is not the first frame of the video, but the frame after 1 second of video.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f image2 -vf fps=1 ./out_%01d.jpg
```

How can I force ffmpeg to extract frames starting at the very first frame of the video?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47671742/

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to also force the very last frame (if not on a round timestamp?). So if video is 3.5s long, frames at timestamps 0, 1, 2, 3 and 3.5s. I tried  round=up:eof_action=pass but am not getting the last frame